# How to initialize a cell with text using init

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, initialization, init

I'm getting stuck with trying to initialize a UICollectionViewCell subclass with some text :( I'm of course quite new to initializers, and my usual lame workaround (for passing data in general, not for cells) is to call a setup function to pass info afterwards. Any wise words? Many thanks in advance.

```
class MainCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let titleLbl: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel() // other stuff was in here
        lbl.text = "Placeholder text"
        return lbl
    }()    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }
    func setupViews() {
        // adding to subviews, constraints, etc. Placeholder text works.
    }
}


class SubCell: MainCell {
    convenience init(title: String) {
        self.init()
        titleLbl.text = title
    }
}


SubCell(title: "Test") // doesn't return a cell with "Test" in the label
```

**Solved:**
Wanted to share my solution in case it could ever help someone out. As @rmaddy pointed out, I was dequeuing cells that weren't getting initialized with my string.

I’ve seen typically these are based on arrays and passing data that way. But I have 4 cells with different elements, and I would like to avoid indexPath logic if possible.

My solution (I’m sure I’m not the only one, but I couldn’t find this anywhere) was to make custom classes for every cell, like how view controllers work. Now I have an array that contains the cells, and if I need to add a new one, I create the cell class and add it to the list without messing with any cellId's or indexPath stuff. Sorry to go on, I’m pretty new and am really excited. Here's my code if anyone wants to roast it:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    let cells = [CellOne(), CellTwo(), CellThree(), CellFour()]
    // subclasses of UICollectionViewCell, defined elsewhere


    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = bgColor

        for cell in cells {
            collectionView.register(type(of: cell), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: type(of: cell)))
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionViewCellSize
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellType = type(of: cells[indexPath.item])
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: cellType), for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to pass the string in the initializer. Cells get reused and you need to update existing cells. Create the cell normally and then update the `tltleLbl` property separately in `cellForRowAt`.

Something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "whatever" for: indexPath)
    cell.titleLbl.text = // whatever value is appropriate for this row

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, I was disregarding that fact that it's getting reused, thanks a ton! I got so wrapped up in things and forgot that it's dequeuing brand new blank cells.

I am pretty ok with setting up tables/collection views by passing data this way, I'm just struggling to make a basic Settings page with finite and straightforward cells, however they're all different. I was hoping to just make an array of cells, premade with properties, hence this. Any tips on this by chance? It's super simple, but I was just seeing if I can break away from doing the conditional logic per cell using indexPath.

Comment: PS I use the term "brand new" very loosely